# Webpack, babel, corejs - generate unnecessary code

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, polyfills, core-js

I would need to explain how to set up babel in combination with a webpack for transpiling and polyfilling JS. I also need to target the IE 11 browser.

**Browserlist settings**

```
"browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "> 0.5%",
    "IE 11"
  ]
```

**Babel settings**

```
module.exports = {
  sourceType: "unambiguous",
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        debug: true,
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        corejs : {
          version : "3",
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
}
```

**Webpack settings**

```
// Path
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
  entry: {
    'app': './app.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/,
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};
```

**app.js**

```
const app = typeof undefined;
```

**app1.bundle.js**
npm run build - generate **2970 lines** of code only for one line in app.js
**91kb unminifed**
**26kb minifed**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMinV.png)

What am I doing wrong?
Well thank you